# iOS app stopped recording analytics for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

We had app developed just before the release of iOS 8 and it was recording Google analytic for iOS 7 but stopped recording for iOS 8. App Developer are saying Google analytic is not compatible with iOS 8 & they are waiting for the new API's which are compatible with iOS is this the fact. as i am not the app developer.

Comment: I cant see anything in the documentation that says the Google Analytics IOS SDK doesn't work with IOS 8.  I sent an email to one of the developers to double check for you.  I will let you know what I hear.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer I am still waiting to hear from the developers.  I have done a bit of research.

If you check the change [log](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/changelog).

> Removed warning messages about GAIHit and GAIProperty classes missing
>   when compiling against iOS SDK 8.0; those classes were removed.

That message implies to me that it does work against IOS SDK 8.

Getting started also states [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/):  `iOS Developer SDK 5.0 or later`

Found some comments on the ga-mobile-app-analytics group:   [Support for iOS 8](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ga-mobile-app-analytics/hktBHr0sGoU)  but I cant see that anyone has logged this to the issue tracker

Issue tracker only has two issues relating to iOS 8 if it wasn't supported I would suspect we would find an issue requesting that it be supported.  [Google Analytics issues](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=ios%208.0&sort=component&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&cells=tiles)

Lets wait to here from the devs.

**Update**:  Directly from the Google Dev.

> It works with ios 8. If they have an actual error message or some
>   details then they should share that and create an issue or star an
>   existing issue in the issue tracker.

Anwser: It works with [Google Analytics SDK for iOS v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) does work with iOS 8.

Comment: DalmTo, Appreciate your response. I will wait for feedback from your developers.

Comment: I got the mail back from him late last night.  Have your devs post an issue if they are having a problem.